# Facebook Graph API: is User Locale Automatically Determined by Geolocation Check?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, geolocation, locale

After doing my research, I could not get an answer for this question:

When a developer gets the `locale` field from the [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), does this locale is based on the user's said country on their profile? Or does Facebook do a geolocation check based on the user's IP for each session to determine the locale?

This is important since I need to know how realiable the `locale` field is.

**EDIT**: So, it all appears that this locale field is indeed based on the user's said locale on their profile (see Richard's answer below). **Is there a way to get a geolocation-checked country code from the FB Graph API?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User.locale` corresponds to the display language the user has selected, eg via the link at the bottom of the home page.

If I change my language from English to Indonesian, for example, my `locale` changes to `id_ID`.

Comment: Thank you @Richard-Barnett. I did a test myself and saw that this code was changed the moment I changed the setting in Facebook. I wonder if there is a way where one can get a geolocation-checked country _from Facebook Graph API_.

Comment: Anyway, this basically answered my main question. Thanks.